# How to add translate feature to my MayaPython cube generator UI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, maya

I'm trying to make a cube layout tool to name and add polyprimatives to my scene, then reference in assets later. I have been able to make a basic UI based on some tutorials I've watched, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a translate feature onto my UI. I have it formatted under location, but when it comes to making it work I am totally stumped, if anyone could help clarify what I need to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code so far.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random 
   #Creates the board to layout buildings, might put into UI later if I have time.
cmds.polyPlane(width=100, height = 100, name = 'Ground')
   #Define class, put DL to avoid confusion between other potential window items.
class DL_Window (object):
    #creates method to construct window, call function "self".
    def __init__(self):
        
        #Creating some attributes, like name, title, and size of the window as it will initially appear on the screen.
        self.window = 'DL_Window'
        self.title = "City Layout Creator"
        self.size = (400,400)
        # will close old window if it's still open
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI (self.window, window= True)
        #creates the new window    
        self.window = cmds.window (self.window, title=self.title, widthHeight=self.size)
        
        #adjusts all UI to fit in the column
        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn = True)
        
        #Create a title, and seperator from the name of the UI, and the function of the UI
        cmds.text(self.title)
        cmds.separator(height = 20, width = 100)
        
        #Some customizable widgets that can adjust name, location of building on map, subdivisions for extruding windows or doors, and lastly the button.
        self.cubeName = cmds.textFieldGrp( label = 'Building Name:')
        self.cubeSize = cmds.floatFieldGrp ( numberOfFields = 3, label = 'size:', value1=1, value2=1,value3=1 ) 
        self.cubeLocation = cmds.floatFieldGrp (numberOfFields = 3, label = 'location:', value1=1,value2=1,value3=1)
        self.cubeSubdivs =cmds.intSliderGrp(field=True, label = 'subdivs', minValue=1,maxValue=20, value=1)
        self.cubeCreateButton = cmds.button(label= 'Create Building', command=self.createBuilding)
        
        #Repeat Steps for Trees
        cmds.separator(height = 20, width = 100) 
        cmds.text("Tree Generator")
        cmds.separator(height = 20, width = 100) 
        
        self.treeName = cmds.textFieldGrp( label = 'Tree Name:')
        self.treeSize = cmds.floatFieldGrp ( numberOfFields = 3, label = 'size:', value1=1, value2=1,value3=1 ) 
        self.treeLocation = cmds.floatFieldGrp (numberOfFields = 3, label = 'location:', value1=0,value2=0,value3=0)
        self.treeSubdivs =cmds.intSliderGrp(field=True, label = 'subdivs', minValue=1,maxValue=20, value=1)
        self.cubeCreateButton = cmds.button(label= 'Create Tree', command=self.createBuilding)           
        
        
        # Displays the window in Maya
        cmds.showWindow()
        
    def createBuilding (self, *args):
        print ("A button has been pressed")
        
        name = cmds.textFieldGrp(self.cubeName, query = True, text=True)
        
        width = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeSize, query=True, value1=True)
        height = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeSize, query=True, value2=True)
        depth = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeSize, query=True, value3=True)
        
        
        transformX = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeLocation, query = True, value1=True)
        transformY = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeLocation, query = True, value2=True)
        transformZ = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeLocation, query = True, value3=True)
        
        subdivs = cmds.intSliderGrp (self.cubeSubdivs, query=True, value=True)
        
        cmds.polyCube(name = name, width = width, height = height, depth = depth, subdivisionsWidth = subdivs,subdivisionsHeight = subdivs,subdivisionsDepth = subdivs)
        
           
# Calling the class here       
myWindow = DL_Window()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it by simply moving the object:

```
    pc = cmds.polyCube(name = name, width = width, height = height, depth = depth, subdivisionsWidth = subdivs,subdivisionsHeight = subdivs,subdivisionsDepth = subdivs)
    cmds.move(transformX, transformY, transformZ, pc)
```

btw. you can simplyfy your floatFieldGrp querys a bit like this:

```
    width, depth, height = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeSize, query = True, value=True)
    transformX,transformY,transformZ = cmds.floatFieldGrp (self.cubeLocation, query = True, value=True)
```